# Unable to import gradle dependency's classes on Kotlin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, import, kotlin, dependencies

I'm having a problem using Gradle, my dependency downloads and is included in the "External Libraries" just fine, but I can't import its classes in IntelliJ IDEA.

See the following pictures:

[image: External Libraries]

[image: Importing Error]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

group 'cf.dogo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

mainClassName = "cf.dogo.core.boot.BootKt"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:3.6.0_376'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.3'
    compile 'com.github.NathanPB:DogoAPI:master-SNAPSHOT' //That one is the problematic dependency
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cf.dogo.core.boot.BootKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Note that it's from [JitPack](https://github.com/NathanPB/DogoAPI).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm testing some things and it imports very well on a java class, but not on kotlin ones

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached. If the issue is Kotlin specific, report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT instead. Thank you.